# How to call javascript method from C++ with parameters using EM_JS

Tags: c++, webassembly, emscripten

I just gone through [Calling JavaScript from C/C++](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html#calling-javascript-from-c-c) and followed their instructions.
I am able to call the Js method from C++

**C++**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <emscripten.h>
#include <emscripten/bind.h>

EM_JS(void, call_js, (), {
    jsMethod();
});

bool callJsBack()
{
    call_js();
    return true;
}

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(module)
{
    emscripten::function("callJsBack", &callJsBack);
}
```

**Js**

```
<script>
    var Module = {
        onRuntimeInitialized: function() {
            console.log('Module.callJsBack(): ' + Module.callJsBack());
        }
    };

    function jsMethod() {
        alert('I am a js method!');
    }
 </script>
```

I want to make the jsMethod() parameterized (want to pass the string from the C++ at the time of calling jsMethod()).

```
function jsMethod(msg) {
    alert(msg);
}
```

I did not find any example or suggestion to achieve this requirement.

Answer (score 5):

Found the answer:

**C++**

```
EM_JS(void, call_js_agrs, (const char *title, int lentitle, const char *msg, int lenmsg), {
    jsMethodAgrs(UTF8ToString(title, lentitle), UTF8ToString(msg, lenmsg));
});

bool callJsBackWithAgrs()
{
    const std::string title = "Hello from C++";
    const std::string msg = "This string is passed as a paramter from C++ code!";
    call_js_agrs(title.c_str(), title.length(), msg.c_str(), msg.length());
    return true;
}

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(module)
{
    emscripten::function("callJsBackWithAgrs", &callJsBackWithAgrs);
}
```

**Js:**

```
var Module = {
    onRuntimeInitialized: function() {
        Module.callJsBackWithAgrs();
    }
};

function jsMethodAgrs(title, msg) {
    alert(title + '\n' + msg);
}
```

complete working example:
[CallJsFromCpp](https://github.com/Anil8753/WASMDemo/tree/master/CallJsFromCpp)